# configuring backup migrate file name in settings file

Tags: configuration

Drupal 9.3.7, backup_migrate 5.0.1 --- On my dev machine, I've set the name for backup_migrate backup files in the config settings. When I export the database to my production machine, I'd like to use a different file name for the backup. How can I do this in the settings.php for the production site? (I have separate settings.php for the dev and prod sites). Can I set a $settings[] var in settings.php? I'm not sure what the name of it would be. In backup_migrate, I set this in a settings profile; is it possible to use a different profile depending on the host?

Comment: Simple way to get the name of config for settings.php: export the config to a file, then look at the name of the file.  [docs here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/configuration-override-system#s-global-overrides)

Comment: Thanks - I saw that, but not sure how to specify the var. I imagine it would be based on backup_migrate.backup_migrate_settings.standard, so what would the variable be? Something like $settings['backup_migrate.backup_migrate_settings']['standard']['name'] ?

Comment: You are on the right track, but pretty sure you are looking for `$config` vs `$settings`. Aside, I like to install the https://www.drupal.org/project/config_override_warn module since it will give some indication within the admin UI that this is controlled elsewhere.

Comment: $config['backup_migrate.backup_migrate_settings']['standard']['name'] = 'backup-en9-local-override';
But when I set a breakpoint (xdebug, using phpStorm) in the settings.php file, $config is shown as being empty. I see my setting added after stepping over the line but I don't see it changed on the b/m settings page.

Comment: Changes in settings.php do not show up in the admin UI, so you won’t see a change. For local development you can use the Config Override Warn module as noted above, but note the warning “do not use this module in production”.